# Magento guest checkout won't make it to shipping info

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, shopping-cart

For some odd reason when people try to use guest checkout it just allows them to enter billing information then when it supposed to go to shipping... it just loops back to the first checkout page... the the process keeps repeating

anyone know where this may be coming from?

the site is [a2iwheels.com/checkout/onepage/](http://a2iwheels.com/checkout/onepage/)

Answer (score 1):

Your Magento install is incorrect. According to this report it looks like you're missing the PHP MCrypt extension:

http://www.a2iwheels.com/report/?id=500049770619&s=default

Here's a few tips when debugging Magento problems:

### First:

Enable debug/developer mode by uncommenting/adding the following lines to the Magento index.php file:

```
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

### Second:

Setup the Magento exception log:

1. In the Magento Admin, go to System->Configuration
2. In the left column, click on Developer (under Advanced)
3. If it’s not expanded, Click on Log Settings
4. Select Yes from the “Enabled” drop down
5. Click on Save Config

Note that you'll need to manually create the log files before Magento begins writing to them.

### Third

Install [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) and use it to catch AJAX errors - the single page checkout is essentially one complicated AJAX page.

Comment: im getting firebug now but, PHP MCrypt is this something i need to install or do i need to reinstall magento?

Comment: Installing the php mcrypt extension should take care of the error.

Comment: I have the site hosted and don't have access to the server, so i should have the server admin install PHP MCrypt and the error should go away... which fixes the checkout problem right?

Comment: Yes, that should fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Go to `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml`

and change the following code (line 36)

```
<fieldset>
   <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```

to this

```
<fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```